# How to compare correlation coeffecients across studies (meta-analysis, simulation-analysis)?

Tags: correlation, simulation, meta-analysis

I have one metric dependent variable (grain yield) and three metric traits, A, B and C. Grain yield and all three traits were measured in several studies and each time a Pearson correlation between trait and grain-yield was reported.

So I have correlation-coeffecients for each combination:

grain yield ~ trait A (around 50 correlation-coeffecient values)

grain-yield ~ trait B (around 50 correlation-coeffecient values)

grain-yield ~ trait C (around 50 correlation-coeffecient values)

*What statistical test would I use to compare these three sets of correlation coeffecients to see which trait is a better predictor for grain yield?*

(One could also think of a scenario where I am doing a simulation study and I look what experimental design allows to predict true values best, in fact this is what I am doing but the example above is easier to explain and understand)

Comment: Do you have the correlations between A and B, A and C, and B and C?

Comment: No, I don't. In my scenario these are also not of any importance.

Comment: But you need them if you want to compute the covariance between the three correlations that you are actually interested in.

Comment: I checked it and I found that I might be able to extract the correlations/covariances between them. But I am just wondering, can I not just do a one-way-ANOVA and a Tukey-test to compare the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot just conduct a one-way ANOVA on the correlations because they are not independent. Within each study, you need to construct the variance-covariance matrix of the correlations (or the r-to-z transformed values). For this, you need to know the correlation between A and B, between A and C, and between B and C. You can find equations for the covariance between correlations in:

Olkin, I., & Finn, J. D. (1990). Testing correlated correlations. *Psychological Bulletin, 108*(2), 330–333. https://doi.org/10.1037/0033-2909.108.2.330

Steiger, J. H. (1980). Tests for comparing elements of a correlation matrix. *Psychological Bulletin, 87*(2), 245–251. https://doi.org/10.1037/0033-2909.87.2.245

So, for each study you then have 3 correlations (between grain yield and the three traits) and a 3x3 var-cov matrix. This can be used as input for a multivariate meta-analysis. See, for example:

Kalaian, H. A., & Raudenbush, S. W. (1996). A multivariate mixed linear model for meta-analysis. *Psychological Methods, 1*(3), 227-235. https://doi.org/10.1037/1082-989X.1.3.227

(this article is not focused on correlations, but the methods are the same). Chapter 16 from *The Handbook of Research Synthesis and Meta-Analysis* by Cooper et al. (2019) also discusses the required methods and is focused specifically on correlation coefficients. You can conduct such an analysis using the [metafor](http://www.metafor-project.org/) package (for the code corresponding to chapter 16 above, see [here](https://wviechtb.github.io/meta_analysis_books/cooper2019.html)) or the [metaSEM](https://cran.r-project.org/package=metaSEM) package.